# Sufficient conditions - Convergence on manifold

Tags: manifolds

I have came to certain problem in a differential question, but I fail to solve it. I look for sufficient conditions to make $q$ to converge to zero.

\begin{equation}
\alpha \dot{q} + \lambda q = 0
\end{equation}

$\alpha$, $\lambda$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. I have already accomplished to conjecturate a necessary condition: if $T = \{t \in \mathbb{R}^+ \, \mid \,\dot{q} = e^{Ct} q(0)\}$, than, for $\theta = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$ and $G = \begin{bmatrix} C \\ I \end{bmatrix}$, hence $S = \{ \alpha, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \, | \, \theta \, G = 0 \}$. It is a $\mathbf{necessary}$ condition since, though $T \Rightarrow S$, the opposite argument is not true ($S \nRightarrow T$). I thank sincerely for the help.

Best regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Let me change a little your notation: you are asking for conditions on a system of differential equations $\alpha \dot{q}(t)+\lambda q(t)=0$,  where $\alpha=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_a &\mathbb{1}\\ \mathbb{1} &\alpha_u \end{bmatrix}$ and $\lambda=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_a &\mathbb{1}\\ \mathbb{1} &\lambda_u \end{bmatrix}$, such that $q(t)\xrightarrow{t\to\infty} 0$.

Well, supposing $\alpha$ is invertible, the original equations are equivalent to $\dot{q}(t)=\left(\alpha^{-1}\lambda\right) q(t)$, which has as solution $q(t)=q(0) e^{\left(\alpha^{-1}\lambda\right) t}$. Hence, your question would be when $ e^{\left(\alpha^{-1}\lambda\right) t}\xrightarrow{t\to\infty} 0$. One simple necessary and sufficient contition that warranties that $ e^{\left(\alpha^{-1}\lambda\right) t}\xrightarrow{t\to\infty} 0$ is that all the real parts of the eigenvalues of $\alpha^{-1}\lambda$ are negative.

Comment: Objection! Your problem is not the one I state. One does not accept your answer. Notice that $\alpha, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Comment: Furthermore, I have already stated something close to what you state (Notice the boldface font text).

Comment: You are right, it seems gave a sufficient condition, BUT the spectral condition is a "if and only if". Hence, apart from the supposition of $\alpha$ be invertible I gave you a necessary and sufficient condition. I will edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I suspect there must have some relation with vec operator.